# Amortized Time with Hash Table

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, hashtable, amortized-analysis

I solved the first part of the question but stuck at the second part.

I have an elevator and want to support the following:

`Init()` Set the elevator to start from floor 0 and its travel direction to be up (This function is called only once and the direction can't be changed). O(1)

`AddStop(K)` save into the DS that elevator should stop when it reaches floor k. O(log n) while n is the total number of stops for the elevator.

`NextStop()` send the elevator to its next stop position, if it's in the final available stop location then the elevator stays at its current place. O(1).

---

My Solution: I used AVL trees such that each node has a pointer to the node that comes exactly after it and the node before it (According to floor number)

When I add new floor I change its 2 pointers accordingly and change the pointers to the effected node in the tree.

**Part 2:**

It's known that after i calls for `AddStop(K)` then the highest floor the elevator could stop at is maximum 2i.

New Complexity Time requirements:

`Init()` - O(1). (Didn't change)

`AddStop(K)` - O(1). Amortized with `NextStop()`

`NextStop()` - O(1). Amortized with `AddStop(K)`

Can someone help me solve part 2?

---

**Update:**

I think part 1 isn't relevant for solving part 2, Plus I highly believe we should use Hash Tables here.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is this condition:

> after *i* calls for `AddStop(K)` then the highest floor the elevator could stop at is maximum *2i*

That means that at worst you're stopping at half the floors, so it's not very wasteful to have an array indexed by floor number, storing a boolean to say whether to stop.

For `NextStop()` simply iterate from the current floor position until you find the next floor to stop at.

To keep the complexity to amortised O(1), whenever AddStop needs a bigger array, it's enough to resize the array to double its previous size.  That way, say you end up with a X floors, 0 to half of them will have been added directly since the last resize, half to 1/4 will have had to be copied once as you resized, 1/4 to 1/8 will have been copied twice, 1/8 to 1/16 copied thrice etc. - at *worst* the number of copies is 1 + 2/2 + 3/4 + 4/8 + 5/16 etc. - it's a limiting sum that Nicole Oresme's theorem says levels out at 4 - a constant factor so still O(1) amortised.

No hash tables involved.

Comment: Thanks, But I have few questions like when should I make my array bigger is it when it's full more than half or when last stop crossed the first half of the array?

Comment: "That means that at worst you're stopping at half the floors," that's not related to what is given because I resize my array always when the last index exceeds half

Comment: If you have an array with say 100 entries, then you can track stops at floors 1 to 100.  If someone calls AddStop(k) where k > 100, then you enlarge the array to at least 200, but possibly as much as k * 2.  That's sufficient to keep the amortised big-O efficient at O(1).

Comment: Again: "That means that at worst you're stopping at half the floors" has nothing to do with the given sentence it's simply true because I double the array size every time I reach the half point... Plus I asked for formal (using accounting method or Aggregate analysis) O(1) amortized with NextStop() which you didn't even mention in your calculation as it could use O(n)

Comment: @MrCalc: I'm not sure what you're having trouble understanding.  Say you add 100 floors, then because of the "after i calls for AddStop(K) then the highest floor the elevator could stop at is maximum 2i" promise, you know those hundred floors are all between 1 and 200, and that the ratio of floors-to-stop-at to floors-to-skip-over is no worse than 1:1, which means there's at worst a constant factor of 2x overhead in comparing empty floors to the unused-floor sentinel value while iterating over all the floors - hence amortised O(1).  If that's not obvious to you yet, I'm afraid I give up.

Comment: @MrCalc You didn't ask for a formal analysis (using accounting or aggregate method) in this question, but in the duplicate question using your sock puppet account: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65485618/how-to-calculate-amortized-time-complexity